# Currently working with Vue. Project in development phase so I used https://unpkg.com/vue. Although the desired text is not displaying

Tags: vue.js

H1 not displaying "Welcome to Vue" it sill displays {{tile}}

```
<div id="myApp">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el : '#myApp' ,
        data : {
            title : 'Welcome to Vue'
        },
    });
```

Comment: is this code added in the vue component? if so then why there are 2 script tags?

Comment: 1 script ag for linking unpkg and another script tag for the vue instances

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code in addition to what **Dan** mentioned in his answer

```js
new Vue({
  template: `<h1>{{ title }}</h1>`,
  data() {
    return {
      title : 'Welcome to Vue'
    };
  }
}).$mount("#myApp");
```